# Why does the category of definable sets of $T^\mathrm{eq}$ have coproducts?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-theory, categorical-logic

For each first-order theory $T$ there is an associated [weak syntactic category](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture2-Syntax.pdf), sometimes also called "the category of definable sets of $T$" and denoted $\mathrm{Def}(T)$.

Also, for each theory $T$ there is an associated theory $T^\mathrm{eq}$ which can be obtained from $T$ by adding quotient sorts for each definable equivalence relation, see e.g. [here 2.3](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~jimenez/Topics_in_Stability_Theory.pdf).

The nLab [claims](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elimination+of+imaginaries#relation_to_indrepresentable_power_objects) that $\mathrm{Def}(T^\mathrm{eq})$ has coproducts.

**Question:** Why? Intuitively, coproducts correspond to the existence of *sum types*. But in $T^\mathrm{eq}$ we only added quotient types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, a theory is called proper if every sort is nonempty (in every model) and there is a sort which has (in every model) at least two elements. Then we have the following theorem: if $\mathbb{T}$ is any proper theory, the syntactic category of $\mathbb{T}^{eq}$ is a pretopos. This is a consequence of the following (non trivial) theorem, which is a generalization of the result found in [1]: call a coherent category proper if every object is a subobject of a nonempty one and if there is a decidable object $D$ such that $D$ and $\neg D$ are nonempty, where $\neg D$ is the complement of the diagonal $\Delta: D \to D \times D$. Then the theorem says that any proper coherent exact category is a pretopos.

In the case of a classical first-order theory, whose models have at least two elements, the syntactic category of $\mathbb{T}^{eq}$ is an exact coherent category, and it will be proper, since $\mathbb{T}$ is. Hence, it is a pretopos and thus it has disjoint coproducts. In fact, for a proper coherent category, the exact completion and the coproduct completion are equivalent.

[1] Victor Harnik: "Model theory vs. categorical logic: two approaches to pretopos completion". In Bradd Hart et al., editor, Models, logics, and higher-dimensional categories: a tribute to the work of Mihaly Makkai, volume 53 of CRM Proceedings and Lecture Notes. American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I., 2011.

Comment: Thanks! Mhm, the nLab (and other places such as https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture8-Topologies.pdf) don't assume T to be proper. So did they forgot that assumption or do they use the convention that (-)^eq adds not only quotients but also one two-element sort?

Comment: @user478652 In general in stability theory one is interested in infinite models, so the assumption is not mentioned explicitly as one expects the theory to have infinite models.

Answer (score 6):

Although godelian has already given a complete answer to this question, I personally like to see explicit constructions for things like this.

Given two definable sets $D_0$ and $D_1$ (in sorts $S_0$ and $S_1$, respectively), a typical construction of the coproduct (or disjoint union) of $D_0$ and $D_1$ assumes that we have some sort $S_2$ in which there are two distinct definable elements, $a_0$ and $a_1$, but it would be nice to not have to assume that there are any definable elements at all. We could also make our lives easier by assuming that the theory is complete, but we won't. I am, however, going to assume that every sort is always non-empty. If you don't have this assumption, I believe that the coproduct of definable sets can't actually be constructed in a uniform way across varying completions of $T$ in the standard version of $T^{eq}$ (i.e., closing the collection of sorts under products and definable quotients), so if you do want to allow for this possibility, I would recommend just modifying the definition of $T^{eq}$ (either adding an explicit two element sort or adding explicit coproduct sorts).

We need, as in godelian's answer, to assume that every model of the theory $T$ has a sort containing at least two elements. A small compactness argument shows that there is a finite sequence $O_0, \dots,O_{n-1}$ of sorts such that every model of $T$ has at least two elements in $O_i$ for some $i<n$.

A definable set equivalent to the disjoint union of $D_0$ and $D_1$ exists in a quotient of the product sort $P = S_0 \times S_1 \times O_0^2 \times \dots \times O_{n-1}^2$. We'll represent an element of this product sort as a tuple $(x,y,z_0,w_0,z_1,w_1,\dots,z_{n-1},w_{n-1})$ or $(x,y,\bar{z},\bar{w})$, where $z_i$ and $w_i$ are variables of sort $O_i$.

The specific equivalence relation we need is
$$E(x,y,\bar{z},\bar{w};x',y',\bar{z}',\bar{w}') \equiv (\bar{z}=\bar{w} \wedge \bar{z}'=\bar{w}' \wedge x = x') \vee (\bar{z}\neq \bar{w} \wedge \bar{z}'\neq \bar{w}' \wedge y = y'),$$
where $\bar{z}=\bar{w}$ is short for $\bigwedge_{i<n} z_i =w_i$ and $\bar{z} \neq \bar{w}$ is short for $\neg(\bar{z}=\bar{w})$.

A little work shows that $E$ is an equivalence relation and that the quotient $P/E$ can be definably identified with $S_0 \sqcup S_1$. Specifically, there are definable injections from $S_0$ and $S_1$ into $P/E$ with disjoint images that cover $P/E$. The coproduct of $D_0$ and $D_1$ can now just be taken to be the union of their images under these injections.

Comment: I don't really get why you are working with a *sequence* $O_0, \dots, O_{n-1}$. Can't one realize $A+B$ as a subquotient of $A\times B\times O$ where $O$ is any sort with at least two elements?

Comment: @user478652 If the theory is incomplete, it may not be the case that $O$ has at least two elements in all models of the theory. For a complete theory, though, we can just use a single $O$ like you say.

Comment: @user478652 Maybe a better way to phrase my argument would be to break it up into two steps. The first would be to show that any proper theory has an imaginary sort that always has at least two elements (namely the product $O_0 \times \dots \times O_{n-1}$), and the second would be what you're suggesting, using that product sort.

Comment: Just fix any sort $O$ with at least two elements. What are $O_0, \dots, O_{n-1}$, what is $n$? I still don't get that.

Comment: @user478652 I'm interpreting the overall question being relative to a possibly incomplete theory rather than relative to a particular structure, and furthermore, I'm establishing that the coproduct can be defined in a uniform way across all models of that theory, rather than just in each model individually. For an incomplete theory, there isn't necessarily a single sort that has at least two elements for every model, even if every model has a sort with at least two elements.

Comment: @user478652 In order for this to work, we need to assume that the theory $T$ is proper, i.e., that every model has a sort with at least two elements. If we assume this, then a compactness tells us that there must be a finite list of sorts $O_0,\dots,O_{n-1}$ such that for any model $M\models T$, there is an $i<n$ such that $|O_i^M| \geq 2$. That's where $n$ comes from.

Comment: As I said, I don't understand that. By the definition goedelian gave, a theory is proper if there is a sort which has at least two elements in every model. Just work with that sort. I don't know why you work with a different definition ("for every model there is a sort with at least two elements" - the quantifiers are the other way around). Also, even if you use that definition, I don't get how your compactness argument works. The compactness theorem says that if each finite subset of a theory has a model, then the theory has a model. To which theory do you apply that?

Comment: @user478652 Ah, you are right. I misread the definition of proper. The compactness argument is just this: Assume that for any finite set of sorts there is a model in which each of those sorts has one element. Then by compactness, there is a model in which all sorts have one element. Since we assumed this can't happen, there must be a finite collection $O_0,\dots,O_{n-1}$ of sorts with the property that any model has at least two elements in one of those sorts. The theory is $T$ together with sentences for each sort saying that that sort has one element.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. So your argument is a bit more general because your assumption ("for every model there is a sort with at least two elements") is strictly weaker than that of proper-ness ("there is a sort which has at least two elements in every model")!